# statement Arrays not working java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

When I try to use Arrays to print out an Arrays to print out my 2D ArrayList it says "Arrays cannot be resolved"

If this isn't how your suppose to print out an Arraylist then how are you suppose to?

Here's my code:

```
package assignment2;
import java.util.*;;

public class BadmintonScoring {
static final int PLAYER1 = 1;
static final int PLAYER2 = 2; 

public static void main(String[] args){
ArrayList<Integer>[][] list = new ArrayList[2][26];
list[0][0] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list[1][1].add(1);
list[2][2].add(2);

for(ArrayList<Integer>[] arr : list){
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}

}
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you haven't got an import for `java.util.Arrays`...

Comment: I did import it, I imported the whole import java.util.*;

Comment: It's hard to tell that when you didn't include it in your post. This is why it's useful to post a *complete* program. With the right imports, your code compiles for me (with a generics warning).

Comment: That odd, mine says that Arrays cannot be resolved.

Comment: Well if you'd post your complete code, we could check. As it is, I've had to add the imports based on your other comment. Which version of Java are you using?

Comment: According to Eclipse I'm using JRE 1.8.0_20 and JDK 1.5 which I'm assuming is default.

Comment: Then I see no reason for this. As you *still* haven't posted a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, I'm voting to close as unreproduceable...

Comment: I don't recommend using JRE 1.8.0_20 and JDK 1.5 together.  You should probably try to use JDK 1.8.something throughout if you're trying to write in Java 8.

Comment: I was trying to fix it so I was playing with it a little

Comment: Well it works fine for me in Eclipse. Try compiling your exact code from the command-line with javac, and I'm sure you'll see it work there too.

Comment: Are you getting that error at run time, or is it a compile error?  And can we have the exact wording please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot these imports

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
```

In below line you get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 0`

```
list[0][0].add(5, 6);
```

**why**?

you used add function to try to add Integer to your 2D array list

> **public void add(int index, E element)**
>
> Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list.
>   Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any
>   subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indices).

You have not add any elements 0 through 4, so basically they are empty. After that you add Integer to index 5 which through the exception for you.

Last point

```
for(ArrayList<Integer>[] arr : list){
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list));
}
```

you need to print out the each elements of your 2D ArrayList which is going to be arr

```
for(ArrayList<Integer>[] arr : list){
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

Comment: Actually, the `2` you're talking about has nothing to do with the ArrayList that he's using `add` on. Notice he's using position `[0, 0]` on the regular array. You're right he'll get an IndexOutOfBoundsException, but wrong about why. It's because there are no elements in the ArrayList at index 6 because it's empty to start.

Comment: ya i figure it out i am updateing my answer

Comment: @mikeyaworski is my answer better?

Comment: @ Supernaturalgirl 1967 did you see my answer?

Comment: I did but the problem I have now is that Arrays cannot be resolved.

Comment: @Supernaturalgirl1967 can you tell what you did?

Comment: I tried importing java.util.Arrays; but I got an error saying that it could not be resolved. and in the main method it also says that Array could not be resolved.

Comment: yeah what's your username?

Comment: @KickButtowski Yup it's better now.

Comment: @mikeyaworski thank you for pointing it out and make me better

Answer (score 2):

```
for(ArrayList<Integer>[] arr : list){
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list));
}
```

Should be:

```
for(ArrayList<Integer>[] arr : list){
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

Comment: +1 for caught this issue first

Answer (score 1):

You've a couple of typos

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer>[][] list = new ArrayList[2][26];
    list[0][0] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list[0][0].add(5);
    list[0][0].add(6);

    for (ArrayList<Integer>[] arr : list) {
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but Arrays still cannot be resolved, and I imported java.util.*;

Comment: sure, you need to do import java.util.ArrayList; and
import java.util.Arrays;